# How to restore windows image created with dd?

Tags: windows, backup, dd

I want to restore my windows image created with `dd`

I used the command

```
dd if=/dev/nvme0n1 of="./$(date).img" status=progress
```

to create the image. There where four partitions in my `nvme0n1`

```
  * EFI system
  * Microsoft reserved 
  * mircosoft basic dat 
  * Windows recovery environment
```

my guess to use

```
dd if=./$(date).img of=/dev/sdaX bs=4m && sync
```

I was wondering what about the UUID of the partitions. Is there something I need to reconfigure.

Comment: Side note: I think you don't want to use `$(date)` when restoring, unless you rename the image to match the close future, wait and hit Enter in the exact second. :)

Comment: Did you try this? You just need to dd the image back to a hard disk, that is all.

Answer (score 0):

Your guess is (almost) correct, that will write the image to a disk, which, in my experience, will then be bootable by most/any EFI capable machine. Though, you would need to write that image to a full disk (like `/dev/sda`) and not to a singular partition (like `/dev/sda1`), since your image contains a partition table with multiple partitions.

In my experience also, there is usually no need to worry about UUIDs too much. Operating systems tend to handle partitions with identical UUIDs gracefully in cases when such exist.

However, if this still bothers you, you can use `ntfslabel --new-serial /dev/sdaX` (provided by `ntfs-3g` package on Arch Linux, for example) to change NTFS serial number to a random one (to my knowledge NTFS doesn't have a UUID as such), and `mlabel -n :: -i /dev/sdaX` (provided by `mtools` package) for FAT filesystem serial numbers.

You can also change GPT partition table's GUIDs for partitions using various tools. For example, you can use `sgdisk -u 1:R /dev/sda` (provided by `gptfdisk` package) to change GUID of the first partition on `/dev/sda` to a random one.

To my knowledge Windows should figure out and properly handle the randomized UUIDs on the next boot, as if nothing happened. However if I'm wrong, it should still be trivial to recover using standard Windows recovery tools.

---

Also, if you are overwriting the original disk with an older image of itself, I don't think there's even a need to worry about UUIDs at all, since at any point in time there's only one visible disk partition with a given UUID.